# How to remove treeview child node using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a treeview like below, i need to remove one child from the list based on the user. Can any one tell me how to remove the child from the treeview.

```
var treedata = [

           {
               label: 'Floor', type: 'Country',
               children: [
                   {
                       label: 'Bangalore', type: 'Location',
                       children: [{ label: 'Technopolis', type: 'facility', id: 1 }, { label: 'Ecity Tower-2', type: 'facility', id: 2 }, { label: 'Bagmane', type: 'facility', id: 3 }, { label: 'Cyber Park', type: 'facility', id: 4 }]
                   },
                   {
                       label: 'Hyderabad', type: 'Location',
                       children: [{ label: 'Hitech City ', type: 'facility', id: 5 }, { label: 'Cyber City', type: 'facility', id: 6 }]
                   },
                   {
                       label: 'Chennai', type: 'Location',
                       children: [{ label: 'XXX', type: 'facility', id: 7 }]
                   },
                   {
                       label: 'Mumbai', type: 'facility', id: 8
                   }
               ]
           },
             {
                 label: 'Role Administration', type: 'Role',
                 children: [{ label: 'Assign Role', type: 'Role', id: 1 }]
             },

{
    label: 'Hoteling Admin', type: 'Hoteling',
    children: [{ label: 'Hoteling', type: 'Hoteling', id: 1 }]
}


];
```

The above is my jquery tree data. I want to remove the role administration if the user is a normal user by checking the user role.

Anyone help me how to do using jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Where's the user role node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.grep()` to filter the array to a new array based on whatever conditions you want.

```
var userRole='normal';
if( userRole === 'normal'){    
    treeview = $.grep(treeview, function(item){
         return item.label != 'Role Administration';
    });    
}
```

**[grep() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)**